# Python dictionary: sum up numerical and remove 'None' values from nested dictionary and assign results to keys of first level

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

It might be very simple but at the moment, I just don't find a solution for my problem.

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
list_of_pps = {'pp_coal': {'b_el': 20200},
'sto_simple': {'b_el': 200000},
'pp_gas': {'b_el': 41000},
'cable1': {'b_el2': 9000},
'cable2': {'b_el': 8000},
'pp_oil': {'b_el': 1000},
'pp_lig': {'b_el': 11800},
'pp_chp': {'b_th': None, 'b_el': 30000},
'pp_chp2': {'b_th': 25000, 'b_el': 25000}}
```

What I want is to sum up all numerical (not None) values on the second level (nested dict) of *list_of_pps* and assign them to the keys of the first level. This would look like this:

```
list_of_pps = {'pp_coal': 20200,
'pp_chp': 30000,
'pp_chp2': 50000,
'pp_lig': 11800,
'cable1': 9000,
'pp_gas': 41000,
'cable2': 8000,
'sto_simple': 200000,
'pp_oil': 1000}
```

I hope this makes it more understandable. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried anything? what is this dict_values

Comment: How are you creating the `list_of_pps`? It looks like you're getting dictionary view objects somehow..

Comment: What is a ```dict_values```

Comment: dict_values was indeed I dictionary view. Sorry, for my vague description. I have now edited my question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated to reflect new question data:

```
clean_pps = {k: sum(filter(None, v.values())) for k, v in list_of_pps.items()}
```

Comment: Since the OP seems to be using 3, I think `filter` will work (and `ifilter` won't exist. :-)  And I think there's a missing `.items()` there.

Comment: dict_values was indeed I dictionary view. Sorry, for my vague description. I have now edited my question!

Comment: This can't work as it is written now, it throws a `ValueError`because of the missing `items()`. But even `{k: next(ifilter(None, v)) for k, v in list_of_pps.items()}` generates `{'pp_chp': 'b_th', 'pp_lig': 'b_el', 'pp_coal': 'b_el', 'pp_oil': 'b_el', 'pp_gas': 'b_el', 'sto_simple': 'b_el', 'cable2': 'b_el', 'cable1': 'b_el2'}` but that is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @BioGeek Good catch on the `items`, but OP edited the question from what his input originally looked like *after* I answered, if that's what the downvote is about.

Comment: Works like a charm. I have chosen this solution because it is a bit shorter and more generic due to the use of _filter()_. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> list_of_pps = dict((key, sum(v for v in value.values() if v is not None)) for key, value in list_of_pps.items())
>>> pprint(list_of_pps)
{'cable1': 9000,
 'cable2': 8000,
 'pp_chp': 30000,
 'pp_chp2': 50000,
 'pp_coal': 20200,
 'pp_gas': 41000,
 'pp_lig': 11800,
 'pp_oil': 1000,
 'sto_simple': 200000}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible implementation of `dict_values`.  That is, assuming I understand your question correctly.

```
def dict_values(l):
    return [x for x in l if x is not None]
```